# GWT: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException for Type 'java.util.HashMap$KeySet'

Tags: gwt

I am getting com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException exception for HashSet.
Initially I thought either HashSet of Long is not supported.
But https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation contains both of these.

What would be the problem?

I am posting the Service method here:

```
public Set<Long> getNamesFromIDs(Set<Long> ids) {
    return manager.getNamesFromIDs(ids);
}
```

Here, manager is the reference to the Manager class which is included from a library.
I am posting the manager method too:

```
public Set<Long> getNamesFromIDs(Set<Long> styleIds) {
    List<Long> listIDs = new ArrayList<Long>(styleIds);
    Map<Long, Discount> personMap = personDAO.getStyleIdToDiscountMap(listIDs, 0);
    return personMap.keySet();
}
```

Detailed Exception Message:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'java.util.HashMap$KeySet'   
was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this 
SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. 
For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = [30002, 30001]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The above classes from java.util are serialized by the custom field serializer.

**Serialization** for the KeySet is not supported by GWT. It does not implement a Serializable interface ( so it is not serializable in java world either)

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "KeySet is not supported by GWT". Do you mean the operation is not supported or the type? But Set is being supported by GWT as mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation#Package_java_util

Comment: KeySet is implemented and its internal to HashSet. It is not Serializable and not meant to be sent over the RPC.

Comment: Try copying the values of KeySet to ArrayList/Hashset to send it over RPC.